# How to interpolate n number of objects between two different shape keys of that object (like tweening but with meshes)

Tags: modifiers, node-editor, shape-keys

I'm trying to create an array of meshes (with the same mesh data) between two different shape keys, interpolating between the two, like when tweening curves in Rhino. So far, all I have been able to do is manually duplicate and adjust the shape key for each object, but this also doesn't quite work as the base and final shape keys seem to change as I make duplicates (?) Any help would be great!

[image: (Rubbish) drawing to illustrate]